# Настройка веб-сервера apache2 или связка nginx+apache

Tags: php, nginx, apache2

Здравствуйте уважаемые пользователи! Мне нужна помощь в решение задачи. В общем проблема такая. У меня есть свой сервер (6 ядер + 6 Гб ОЗУ + SSD NVMe). Стоит сейчас для проектов apache2 + mod_php + mpm_itk + mpm_prefork + mariadb + php5.6. При большой нагрузке (примерно 300-500) начинает висеть сервер. Советуют перейти на связку nginx + apache. Будет ли это лучше? Так же лучше ли будет связка nginx + php-fpm? На скриптах стоит .htaccess везде, нужно чтобы его читало или какую-то аналогию.
 1. Стоит ли менять голый apache2 на связку nginx + apache2? mod_php так же нужно оставить вместе с mpm_prefork для связки nginx + apache2?
 2. Есть ли для nginx + php-fpm какие-то варианты замены .htaccess, но чтобы так же лежали в папках скрипта? Заранее спасибо за помощь всем.

Comment: Варианты замены .htaccess зависят от того, что в этом .htaccess написано. И при чём тут лежание в папках, непонятно

Comment: .htaccess лежит не в 1 папке, в корне 1, в других другие со своими настройками. Тот, который лежит в корне, там много правил.

Comment: Ну, это всё равно ни о чём не говорит. Если эти правила можно реализовать другим способом — значит от апача можно избавиться, если нельзя — значит нельзя.

Comment: Я могу переписать эти правила под другой аналог, но чтобы они подгружались так же с корня скрипта по типу .htaccess.

Comment: не хотите начать с пхп 7.3-7.4 и opcache? и в целом ревизию кода провести, а то можно его так написать, что никакое железо и оптимзиаци не помогут. выяснить мб сначала в чем именно проблемы ?

Comment: Да зачем мне opcache? Он только будет тормозить работу скрипта, так как для него ставить ещё и opcache просто дебилизм. Меня интересует конкретно связка  nginx+apache.

Comment: `300-500` - это запросов в **секунду**? Если нет, любые манипуляции на уровне веб-серверов бесполезны, вам нужно смотреть скорость веб-приложения. Если да - nginx + php-fpm, правила `.htaccess` элементарно переписываются в конфиги nginx. `Стоит ли менять голый apache2 на связку nginx + apache2` - стоит. `php-fpm какие-то варианты замены .htaccess, но чтобы так же лежали в папках скрипта` - Это невозможно

Comment: `Да зачем мне opcache? Он только будет тормозить работу скрипта, так как для него ставить ещё и opcache просто дебилизм.` - вы сильно заблуждаетесь